# Call to main actor-isolated instance method XXX in a synchronous nonisolated context

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

I am trying to add an async do/catch/defer action to a UIButton. However, if I just call a method in the defer block, I get `Call to main actor-isolated instance method XXX in a synchronous nonisolated context` error. The workaround I found is to wrap it in another `Task` block, like the following. Just want to check if this is the correct way to do it? It'd be good if someone can explain what that error message actually says.

```
@objc private func post(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Task {
        // defer { dismiss(animated: true) } -- Doesn't work
        defer { Task { await dismiss(animated: true) } }
        do {
            try await doSomethingAsync()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actor methods are asynchronous. They are asynchronous because you don't know when they will be run - to prevent multiple methods simultaneously being run on the actor. So you are basically trying to run an asynchronous method in a synchronous context, which you can't do. It's almost like when calling an `async` method in a normal function _not_ marked `async`.

Comment: The other work-around is to not `defer`. If you want it to happen if only successful, then put it after the `doSomethingAsync` call. If you want it to happen whether successful or not, put it after the `do`-`catch` block.

Answer (score 19):

This is bug in current swift versions as compiler is not able to recognize the global actor context for a `defer` block, [the discussion for this is going on swift forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/a-bug-cant-defer-actor-isolated-variable-access/50796/2) and a [PR](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/60688) with fix also available that should resolve this issue in future swift versions. For now, explicitly global actor context need to be provided for code to compile:

```swift
defer { Task { @MainActor in dismiss(animated: true) } }
```